# Wait for WMIC to finish remote call

Tags: windows, wmic

I am using wmic to execute some remote tasks, however, I cannot force it to wait for the completion. Say for example the following:

```
wmic process call create "cmd.exe /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul","C:\Data"
```

wmic process terminates, while another cmd window is sleeping for 10 seconds.

I want the wmic process to wait for the opened cmd session to finish (i.e waiting 10 seconds in this case). Is this possible?

**UPDATE**: I am looking for a non-batch solution

Answer (score 2):

Next batch script could work for you:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

REM get the global process identifier
set "_ProcessId="
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('

  wmic process call create "cmd.exe /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul"^,"%temp%"^|find /I "ProcessId"

') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;= " %%g in ("%%~G") do set "_%%~g=%%~h"

REM wait while the process is running
If defined _ProcessId (
    call :waitForEnd
) else (
    rem debugging output     echo NO process was created
)

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:waitForEnd
    rem debugging output 
    echo waiting until [%_ProcessId%] terminates %time%
    rem set appropriate number of seconds to wait in next timeout command
    >NUL 2>&1 timeout /T 4 /NOBREAK
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%G in ('
        tasklist /FI "PID eq %_ProcessId%" /FO csv /NH
    ') do if /I NOT [%%G]==[INFO] goto :waitForEnd 
    rem debugging output 
    echo       process [%_ProcessId%] terminated %time% 
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\39599427.bat

waiting until [2420] terminates 23:24:52,77
waiting until [2420] terminates 23:24:56,21
waiting until [2420] terminates 23:25:00,20
      process [2420] terminated 23:25:04,22

==>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found JosefZ's comment helpful, but the waiting loop only works if you start processes locally on the server that is running the script.  In my case, I needed to start a process on a different server and then wait for it to finish.

By adding the /NODE: switch you start the process remotely.  Which mean now to read the tasklist you need to run that remotely, and the only way I could figure out to read that back to the script was this clunky method of writing the output to a file and then reading it via a file share.

```
:waitForEnd
echo waiting until [%_ProcessID%] terminates %time%  >> %logfile%
>NUL 2>&1 timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK
wmic /NODE:"RemoteServerName" process call create "cmd /c F:\Scripts\Batch\ProcMon.bat %_ProcessId%"
for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%G in (
    \\<remoteServerName>\<ShareName>\procmon.log
) do if /I NOT [%%G]==[INFO] goto :waitForEnd
echo process [%_ProcessID%] terminated at %time%  >> %logfile%

:: wrap-up
echo %date% %time% "Processing completed" >> %logfile%
ENDLOCAL
goto:eof
```

Then on the remote server, below is the F:\Scripts\Batch\ProcMon.bat:

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq %1" /FO csv /NH > F:\Scripts\Batch\procmon.log
```